# What is difference between loan fees and interest?

Tags: loans, mint.com

I am using Mint. There are several categories for the loan.

My understanding is that both **Loan Fees and Charges** and **Loan Interest** are what I pay to the bank.

What is the difference between them? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interest is simply the charge or cost of borrowing the money, it is charged as a percentage rate of the outstanding amount of the loan.

Loan Fees and Charges are usually a dollar amount (but can be expressed as a percentage) charged on the account. Examples could be Loan Establishment Fee, monthly Account Keeping Fees, and Dishonour Fee.

Fees and charges are charged over and above the Loan Interest.

Comment: Another common type of loan fee is a loan prepayment fee when payment has been made before schedule on a loan contract that does not allow for such prepayments. This is standard on residential mortgage loans.